# Parse data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys I'm a newbie of JavaScript and I tried a lot before posting here.

I have two input tags where i'm using Datapicker from jquery UI to pick some data range.
After I select these values with jQuery method `.val()`, but the problem is that Datepicker use this type of data form: `12/30/2013`, but I need to parse this data in this way: `2013-10-21T00:00:00` because I must use this date range to call a `getJSON` method to call a webserver. I wrote also this function to parse manually. Bellow is my code, what's wrong? In general I want to find a way to translate the data from input tags in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` because our web server accept through rest this format.

```
<input id="from" type="text" class="datepicker" />
<input id="to" type="text" class="datepicker" />
<input id="submit" value="Send" type="submit" />
<script>      
$(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    $("#submit").click(function () {

        var from = $('#from').val();
        var to = $('#to').val();

        function parse(i) {
            var t = i.toString().split("/");
            var y = t[2];
            var m = t[0];
            var d = t[1];
            var n_d = y.concat("-") + m.concat("-") + d.concat("T00:00:00");
            return n_d;
        }


    $.getJSON("xxxx/?from=" + parse(from) + "&to=" +parse(to));

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/722135

Comment: Take a look at http://momentjs.com, it's really powerful when working with dates.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Date.parse` and `Date.prototype.toISOString`:

```
var date = Date.parse('12/30/2013');//1388347200000
date = new Date(date);//"Mon Dec 30 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (MSK)"
date.toISOString;//"2013-12-29T20:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: Note that `Date.parse` is known to have issues, and even on MDN the compatabilty table is just a bunch of red questionmarks, as you never really know what happens when you use `Date.parse`, it could work in some browsers, it could not work in some browser, noone really seem to know? `toISOString` is also only supported in IE9 and up, so generally it's consider good practice to build the string yourself.

Comment: Yes, but there are many polyfills. You can use [one](https://github.com/ckozl/JavaScript-iso8601-Date-Parsing--xbrowser-polyfill-) of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the actual date objects by using `$(element).datepicker('getDate')`, and then just parse those to the wanted format and send away :

```
Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
    var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
    return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
}

function parseDate(d) {
    return [d.getDate().padLeft(), (d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(), d.getFullYear()].join('/')+'T'+
           [d.getHours().padLeft(), d.getMinutes().padLeft(), d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
}

$(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate');
        var to   = $('#to').datepicker('getDate');

        $.getJSON("xxxx/?from=" + parseDate(from) + "&to=" + parseDate(to));
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8BuV/)

I'm guessing you would have to url encode those dates as well, and it probably would be better to just do

```
$.getJSON("xxxx/", {from : parseDate(from), to : parseDate(to)});
```